# openstack conatiner runtime change

Tags: openstack, kolla-ansible

I'm install openstack wallaby using kolla-ansible deployment method. (ubuntu)
I want to chagne container runtime engine(running on controller and compute node)   from docker to cri or containerd. is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`globals.yml`](https://github.com/openstack/kolla-ansible/blob/ddadaa282e72cc437470859766ac963ac757a26a/etc/kolla/globals.yml#LL82C1-L87C33) `docker` is the only option.

```
################
# Container engine
################

# Valid options are [ docker ]
# kolla_container_engine: docker
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I think there is no that parameter in kolla-ansible.

Comment: `it doesn't work`? The answer is that Docker is the only option. There is nothing that should `work`.